# Sync desktop and mobile data

Tags: .net, synchronization

I am looking for some information: i have a website for desktop and mobile phones and i have to share some information between them (e.g. if the user is locked on desktop - lock him on phone too, name updated on phone - update on desktop too, etc).

What is the best way to do this? 
I don't want each call to interrogate the DB to get all the information.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use MQTT to tranfer real-time data, mobile-website without use db.
Demo link:
http://www.hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/

If need, I can do a demo for you.

Good luck!